# Passing an array of pointers to a struct to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a function where an array of pointers to a struct is declared

```
void functionA(argument1, argument2) {
   ...
   struct1 *point[2];
   ...

   functionB(*point, ...) // Call the function ?
}

// Declare the function ?
void functionB(struct1 *point[], ...) {


}
```

I need to pass this array `*point[2]` to another function say functionB where i need to so some operations based on the `point[0]` and `point[1]` what is the correct way to do this ?

When I am calling the `functionB` in `functionA` like `functionB(*point, ...)`, I am getting the error of **incompatible pointer types** whereas when I am calling it like `functionB(*point[], ...)` I am getting the error that **expected expression before `]` token**.

Comment: Have you tried functionB(point)?

Comment: I recommend that you replace `struct1 *point[]` in the argument declaration for `functionB` and replace it with `struct1 **point` to **not** do mistakes like `sizeof(point)` within the function because that won't work. You can pass an array as an argument, however it will be "denoted (? don't remember correct term)" to a pointer (to the first array item) in the called function. If you declare an array in a function, you can however do `sizeof` on that array in that scope. That's why it might be misleading.

Comment: @Jite There is no reason to use pointer-to-pointers here.

Comment: @Lundin It was meant in generic terms though, if it's `struct *point` and `struct point[]` or `struct **point` and `struct *point[]` (...) doesn't really matter. The point I was trying to make was that specifying function arguments as arrays instead of (pointer to ...) pointer is IMO bad practice and might lead to making unnecessary mistakes like `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jite No, common sense dictates that specifying an array as argument to a function expecting an array is good practice. Doing so leads to _self-documenting code_. As it happens, array parameters to functions will decay into pointers to the first object, but just because the C language has this weird feature, it doesn't mean that you should write programs where you have done the "decay" manually. It makes type compatibility checking (by intelligent tools other than the average compiler) impossible and it makes the program harder to read.

Comment: @Jite And the sizeof issue shouldn't be a problem, if the programmer doesn't know about array decay in functions, no coding style will save them. If you need to use sizeof inside the function, you should use an array pointer: `void func (size_t size, int (*arr)[size])
{
  printf("%zu", sizeof(*arr));
}`  Or just `sizeof(int) * size`.

Comment: @Lundin I don't agree with you and I wouldn't draw the conclusion that it's common sense either. I just had a quick Google about it, seems like Torvalds agree with me about this: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428 (well the most common way would be to send along size (in some form) in another argument)

Comment: @Jite The array decay rule is found at 6.7.6.3/7: `A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the
array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
elements as specified by the size expression.`

Comment: @Jite As we can see, you declare parameters as arrays, but they always decay into pointers. C is not Torvald's strongest skill (his strongest skill is arrogance). This: "because array arguments in C don't
actually exist. Sadly, compilers accept it for various bad historical
reasons, and silently turn it into just a pointer argument. There are
arguments for them, but they are from weak minds." is just nonsense. I would like to hear him explain what `void func (int array [static 5])` is.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, I guess we could go on and discuss corner cases (really how common is the usage of `void func (int array [static 5])`, there are other better practical solutions IMO...). We agree to disagree, I think we should keep it at that then.

Comment: @Jite Yes it is barely ever used, but it is an example which shows that parameters must be regarded as arrays, even though they decay into pointers.

Comment: (Also I doubt Linus Torvalds ever used a static analyser, so he is oblivious to the increased type safety argument. If you used one on the Linux kernel, the analyser would probably implode.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call is wrong. `functionB` is expecting its argument of type `struct1 **` but you are passing an argument of type `struct1 *`. Function call should be

```
functionB(point, ...);
```

You should know that as per C rule, when an array is passed to a function then array decays to pointer to it's first element. `point` in function call will decay and will have type `struct1 **` after decaying.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated if anything is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
void functionA(argument1, argument2) {
   ...
   struct1 *point[2];
   ...

   functionB(point, ...) // Call the function ?
}

// Declare the function ?
void functionB(struct1 ** point, ...) {

  // Use point[1] and point[2] here
}
```

Comment: does `functionB(struct1 ** point, ...)` and `functionB(struct1 *point[ ], ...)` would mean the same ? given both of them are pointers to pointers

Comment: Yes. Both are same as a function parameter.

Answer (score -2):

When you need to send an array to a function, you just have to send the base address of that array (i.e. the name) to that function, and then receive it using a pointer to that type. And this rule applies to every data type, be it an `int` or a `struct`.

---

So, You can do

```
void functionA(argument1, argument2) {
   ...
   struct1 *point[2];
   ...

   functionB(point, ...) // Sending base address of array point
}

// Recieve it this way
void functionB(struct1 *point[], ...) {

// Or
void functionB(struct1 **point, ...) {
```

Answer (score -2):

Function `functionB` is declared as having the first parameter of type `struct1 *point[]`

```
void functionB(struct1 *point[], ...) {


}
```

And the array `point` has the same type of elements.

So you just need to use the name of the array as the argument for the function call

```
functionB(point, ...) // Call the function ?
```

Take into account that parameters declared as arrays are adjucted to pointers to their elements.

Thus this function declarations

```
void functionB(struct1 *point[], ...);
```

and

```
void functionB(struct1 **point, ...);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

On the other hand array designators used in expressions are converted to pointers to their first elements. So the expression `point` used as an argument is converted to pointer of type `struct1 **` that is it exactly corresponds to the expected by the function argument according to its declaration.